# Lot of Windows Logs within a minute for SQL Server Login and Windows Logon attempts

Tags: sql-server, windows

I have been facing issue in my Windows Server 2008 R2 that there are thousands of Audit failure logs and MSSQLSERVER logon failed attempts logs as follows.

**1. Audit Failure Log Details :**

An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       &*****
    Account Domain:

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc000006a

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   MSTSC
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.

**2. SQL Server Logon Attempt Log Details:**

Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 119.10.26.166]

Note: The Server has been hosted by Godaddy

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying to brute force their way onto your server. As the server is being hosted by GoDaddy, then i assume it's a remote server. You *are* limiting where connections to the SQL Server can come from to a specific IP, or set of IPs, or only permitting connections from the LAN and your using a VLAN? Right...? *(I suspect very much that the answer to this question is no, and that the whole world has access to port 1433 on your remote host. you need to limit those IPs. NOW.)

Comment: I'm not dissing the hacking comment from @Larnu, (especially since it's hosted by GoDaddy), but you may want to also look at old agent jobs or processes that might have been running since the dawn of time and the `sa` password might have changed in the meantime.

Comment: I agree with @WEI_DBA, check any connected application that you use on client side, you might find an old process that has been depreciated partially, and needs to be fixed. If you're using a third-party tools for reports (such as Crystal Reports) then you should check that too.

Comment: @WEI_DBA very true point. My thought line is mainly due to the fact that the OP isn't a LAN IP (or of it is, someone isn't using the one's they're supposed). If the OP was using a VPN, then it would still be a LAN IP as well. Of course, it could be that they have those IPs limited, and it's one of those that it is limited to. If so, that means the OP should know who's IP that is, or can find out and then what that host at the IP does. Something which h js a really important piece of informtion here, if they do/can have details on what that IP is. :)